# WPF Ribbon: Maximized window going off screen

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ribbon

I'm using the `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` library for my application. Everything is working really nice, except when I maximize the window it starts to go off screen.

I also noticed that with other WPF applications but when you use a `RibbonWindow` it gets worse.

[image]

Here is my source code (nothing really exciting i think):

```
<RibbonWindow 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="LightSteelBlue">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Ribbon Grid.Row="0">
            <RibbonTab x:Name="TestRibbon" Header="TestRibbon">
                <RibbonGroup>
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="TestButton" Label="Button" LargeImageSource="traffic_lights_green.png" />
                </RibbonGroup>
            </RibbonTab>
        </Ribbon>

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1">
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

Is there some way to stop the window from doing this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12567883/183367 if it helps.

Comment: Microsoft Bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775972/wpf-ribbon-window-the-border-is-too-thin

Comment: Just use http://fluent.codeplex.com/ it's much more convenient to use, and even the beta version work just fine for multiple of our productiv applications

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already found it, I think this may answer your problem.
[systemmenu-does-not-show-correctly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/06/systemmenu-does-not-show-correctly-when-ribbon-application-is-run-against-net-4-0.aspx).  It appears to be a bug specific to .net 4 implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know how I "solved" this. I'm using the Fluent Ribbon api. Which works much better for me, also you get the Office 2010 Styles.

But I highly recommend that you download the source code and compile it yourself because the last stable release was a while ago, but it's still under development and the developers respond very quickly to bugs.

http://fluent.codeplex.com/