# Replacing Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon with the new System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon

Tags: .net, wpf, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary, system.windows.controls.ribbon

I just replaced the `Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` with the new `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon`.

If I maximize my application the window now seems to be slightly too big. So that the upper left icon and the icons in the QuickAccessToolbar are only shown partially.

Is it enough to just replace the Ribbon, or do I have to do more?

You can reproduce this problem by just creating a new WPF application and using `RibbonWindow` instead of `Window` as the base class for `MainWindow`.

BTW: The `MainWindow` title disappears when using `RibbonWindow`.

Comment: You mean missing cca 2-3 pixes from icons? I think it depends also whether you use Aero or not - display settings in Windows. Main Window title does not disappear, should be on the right of the QuickAccess.

Comment: You can vote for it on the uservoice website of visual studio:  http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6736521-ribbon-styles-update-to-look-like-office-2013

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF RibbonWindow + Ribbon = Title outside screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567455/wpf-ribbonwindow-ribbon-title-outside-screen)